# Knockout internal/external modules !== transient/singleton lifestyles?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, durandal, amd

When using an IoC container, I can specify that when a given dependency is needed, that either a new object is passed-in each time, or that the object passed-in is always the same instance.

I had thought that internal and external modules respectively provided that functionality, but now I'm not so sure. In addition, I find that my custom binding in Knockout receives "undefined" as the `viewModel` argument when using an "internal" module.

How can I get to choose between singleton and transient with external modules?

I'm using Durandal (Knockout, RequireJS) in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

> "undefined" as the viewModel argument when using an "internal" module

This is a common error that has to do with JavaScript emit ordering. More on this here : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

> When using an IoC container, I can specify that when a given dependency is needed, that either a new object is passed-in each time, or that the object passed-in is always the same instance.

An external module system is not the same as an IoC container. A module is a *singleton* and you always get the same instance. If you want to have different instances have your module export a function (which can act as a factory to the object you actually want).